# What is the word for someone who had the same job or position as someone else in the past?

Tags: word-usage

I know that the word "predecessor" is used to mean "a person who held a job or office before the current holder". But the question is: Can it be applied to someone who had the same job as you in the past?

For example, both Greenblatt and Eliot are critics, but Eliot is dead now. Now can we say Eliot is Greenblatt's predecesssor since the former lived as a critic before the latter.

Comment: I'm surprisingly uncomfortable with the example of Eliot and Greenblatt, viewing it as fraught with complications, not least of which is the assumption inherent in a claim that 'Eliot is Greenblatt's predecessor' based solely on chronology. The case for that claim, in my view, is much more complicated than simply temporal and would require establishing the intellectual, literary and cultural inheritance(s) from Eliot to Greenblatt.

Comment: No. Predecessor is only if one person _replaces_ another in a position at a company.

Comment: Sorry, BeatsMe, and you seem to have ignored the idea that you need to research the subject…

Could you post some research, with perhaps a conclusion for analysis, or were you just hoping for some vague guesses?

Comment: Say that Martha becomes the new manager of Pizza Hut on Main Street.  John was the manager of that Pizza Hut last week, but he got promoted to a job at headquarters.  Harry was the manager of a Pizza Hut on Maple Drive for 10 years up until last year when he retired.  John is Martha's predecessor.  Harry is not.  What would you call Harry?  I have no idea.  I don't even know if there's a word for that.  That's why this isn't an answer but a comment.  What I do know is that you wouldn't call him Martha's predecessor.

Comment: “Predecessor once-removed”. Like a royal cousin or something. Not really a formal term but most people would get it.

Answer (score 1):

Predecessor primarily means what you've written: a person who held a job or office before the current holder. So, it applies when we are talking of a *specific* position like "(official) Critic at so-and-so organisation/establishment". For a *critic* in general, it is not very appropriate as there can be multiple *critics* existing in parallel (perhaps employed by different establishments or even in "freelance" capacity).

The terms preceded & predated are more appropriate in this context.

> As a critic, Eliot ***preceded/pre-dated*** Greenblatt.

ODO:

> **[precede](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/precede)**   VERB   [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Come before (something) in time.
>
> ‘She was preceded in death by her husband and is survived by two
>   daughters.’
>
> **[predate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/predate)** 
>   *VERB* [WITH OBJECT]
>   Exist or occur at a date earlier than (something)
>
> ‘What that shows is that there is a natural global low frequency
>   electromagnetic signal pre-dating life on earth, so we have evolved in
>   the presence of this signal.’

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are explicit in the subject area. So e.g. Eliot **is a predecessor of** Greenblatt, **as a literary critic**.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of predecessor is successor - a person who has a job, position, or title after someone else : someone who succeeds another person

Comment: That's not what the question was asking.